# Asterisk setup for Beginner

Tags: asterisk

I am doing a project to Generate a call automatically to the customer with IVR support. The customer will input a PIN number. I have to extract this PIN number using Java/scripts on the Backend.

I am planning to use Asterisk server for this purpose. To setup a development environment, can I connect a test Mobile phone over serial/USB to a Linux server running Asterisk?. If this is possible, can you please guide to me to some relevant documentation for doing this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a mobile phone to test your Asterisk setup.

Just connect a soft phone (there are free SIP clients such as xlite) to your Asterisk server and perform your testing.

To program your IVR interaction, you can use [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI) - you can do this in a number of languages including Java. The AGI scripts allow you to do IVR specific interactions such as playing a prompt and reading a DTMF input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [twillio](http://www.twillio.com)? They sound like they do exactly what you want...If your in the US.

Comment: I am in India. So this SaaS solution may not fit my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Im in australia, so its no good for me either. Damn US -centric startups... there is a market outside of the US you know :)